# How Can I Get a List of Account the Current User has Delegate Access To?

Tags: sharepoint, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm looking for a way to get a list of accounts to whom the current user has delegate permission. I found the [getDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb799735%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) method on Exchange Web Services, but that method returns the list of users I've given delegate access to, I need the other way around. i.e. given an assistant, tell me the list of managers to whom he/she has delegate permissions.

Ideally I'd like to use a web service, but if that's not possible I can wrap any other solution and build my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can do that in EWS, in good ol' Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) you will need `PR_EMS_AB_PUBLIC_DELEGATES` and its counterpart `PR_EMS_AB_PUBLIC_DELEGATES_BL`.
[Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) exposes this functionality through the [RDOAddressEntry](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressEntry.htm).`Delegates` and `RDOAddressEntry.IsDelegateFor` collections